# QtWidgets/QApplication without using a .pro file

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

When building MAME I get this error:

```
make
GCC 4.9.2 detected
Compiling src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.cpp...
../../../../../src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.cpp:20:30: fatal error: QtWidgets/QApplication: No such file or directory
 #include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
qtdbg_sdl.make:361: recipe for target '../../../../linux_gcc/obj/x64/Release/qtdbg_sdl/src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.o' failed
make[2]: *** [../../../../linux_gcc/obj/x64/Release/qtdbg_sdl/src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.o] Error 1
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'qtdbg_sdl' failed
make[1]: *** [qtdbg_sdl] Error 2
makefile:1003: recipe for target 'linux_x64' failed
make: *** [linux_x64] Error 2
```

How do I fix this error without a .pro file, because I can't find one anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is the building process of a qt application:

```
~$ qmake -project /*this makes .pro file*/
~$ qmake -makefile /*this creates makefile*/
~$ make
```

you always need to run qmake first in order to create correct makefile

```
~$ echo "happy qt coding"
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. You do not need either qmake or a .pro file to build a qt application.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3632038/1227469) for example. The only (possible) requirement is moc, which generates standard c++ that you can run through any compiler (or build tool)

Comment: so, what is the command to compile a simple hello world qt app?

Comment: Well that would depend on your compiler but `g++ helloworld.cpp` should suffice for the simplest case (where none of your code requires moc)

Comment: Qt's IDE and build tool are optional and separate features from the framework itself.

Comment: I already HAVE a makefile. I need some way to compile without a .pro or a way to turn a makefile into a .pro.