# Error compiling Qt application directly with g++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I try to learn C++ with Qt following examples from a book. On very first example including Qt I have a compilation error:

```
$ g++ -Wall qtdemo.cpp
qtdemo.cpp:1:19: fatal error: QString: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The g++ works fine if I don't include any Qt library. 
I try to run the same program using Qt Creator and it works if I do a "Qt Console application" but shows error if I do a "Plain C++ application".
I tried to give a path to `QString` after g++ command, different configuration etc. It seems g++ can't see Qt at all. 
I even installed Qt5 on top of already existing on Ubuntu 16.04 Qt4.
When I check if I have Qt installed it looks everything should be fine:

```
$ locate QString
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/QString
...
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QString
...
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QString
...

$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

The code I try to run:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);

int main() {
        QString s1("This "), s2("is s "), s3("string");
        s1 += s2; //concatenation
        QString s4 = s1+s3;
        cout << s4 << endl;
        cout << "The length of that string is " << s4.length() << endl;
        cout << "Enter a sentence with withspace: " << endl;
        s2 = cin.readLine();
        cout << "Here is your sentence: \n" << s2 << endl;
        cout << "The length of your sentnce is: " << s2.length() << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to make Qt application works from command line with g++ and where the error comes from.

Comment: Stuff under /opt isn't (normally) in the usual library or include file search paths of linkers, so you have to give appropriate compiler options. But, just use *qmake* or *qbs* to manage your Qt project, because you don't want to be doing this stuff by hand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For building qt projects (which can also be c++ projects containing qt libs) I would strongly advise to look at the qmake tools (e.g. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html for qt4.8 or http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html for qt5).

As the manual says

> qmake is a tool that helps simplify the build process for development project across different platforms

For your code the only thing I needed to do to compile was to put the code into a `main.cpp` file and then I did

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

and got a working executable.

During the `make` command you will also see the full command that it executed which will be along the lines of

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o main.o main.cc
```

which contains various include paths as well as other things, but unless you have very specific things to do I would (personally) refrain from doing things by hand.

Even if you have specific customization to do, this can be done via the `.pro` file that is created when doing `qmake -project`. You can look at the documentation for these types of files

- for qt4.8: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html
- for qt5: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score -1):

The compiler has to know the Qt libraries and then after compilation you have to link against them. Instead of `g++ -Wall qtdemo.cpp` try at least `g++ -Wall -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread qtdemo.cpp`

If `-lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread` are unknown you have to set the path with the `-I` option

See this thread for a working solution, especially the *qmake* makefile that *Quent42340* posted:

[Can I use Qt without qmake or Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632038/can-i-use-qt-without-qmake-or-qt-creator)