# How to use Qt libraries in UWP project?

Tags: c++, qt, uwp, visual-studio-2017, lnk2019

I have a UWP project for which I wish to use some of the QtCore and QtNetwork classes. I have successfully included the headers, and I added the "lib" folder of Qt in the Additional Library Directories option of the Linker. When trying to build the project I get a lot of errors like

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall *CLASSNAME* etc etc

and LNK2001 errors with similar error strings.
All the resources I found on the internet talk about qmake, .pro files, moc and other things I've never heard of, but they don't give me a real explanation of what to do to make this thing work. They only suggest to create a QtProject, but that is not possible as I am using UWP.

So my question can be reassumed as this: what do I have to do to import and use some Qt libraries in my non-Qt project the same way I would import generic 3rd-party libraries?

Comment: Hi, that's possible to use qt outside of Qt Creator but it depends on application. Please check out the flags used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632038/can-i-use-qt-without-qmake-or-qt-creator I believe that's the field in which you can look for solution. People use qmake, CMake.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already checked that thread, but as I'm not an expert of C++ and I don't know how to manage makefiles or run qmake, moc and the other things mentioned in there, I was looking for some documentation or step-by-step tutorial that could teach me what to do.